# Java Parsing Oracle Explain Plan

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, sql-execution-plan

I wonder if there is any library that allows for parsing oracle's explain plan into a data structure.

Given the following query:

```
 select prod_category, avg(amount_sold)
 from sales s, products p
 where p.prod_id = s.prod_id
 group by prod_category;
```

explain plan may look something like the following:

```
 ------------------------------------------
  Id   Operation              Name   
 ------------------------------------------
    0  SELECT STATEMENT              
    1   HASH GROUP BY                
    2    HASH JOIN                   
    3     TABLE ACCESS FULL   PRODUCTS
    4     PARTITION RANGE ALL        
    5      TABLE ACCESS FULL  SALES  
 ------------------------------------------
```

I want a parser that parses the plan into a data structure that allows visualizing and analyzing the plan like the following:

```
  SELECT STATEMENT
        |
     GROUP BY
        |
       JOIN
   _____|______
  |            |
 ACCESS     ACCESS
 (PRODUCTS) (SALES)
```

I have noticed that Oracle's [SQLDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) visualizes the plan. I am reluctant to manually parse the text, so I wonder if there is any library that would help with parsing the plan.

Comment: I think you can request explain plan in XML using JDBC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plan is already stored as hierarchical structure for easy visualization:

```
  select 
    id, 
    parent_id, 
    lpad(' ', 2*(level-1), ' ')||operation||' '||object_name as desc
  from your_plan_table
  start with parent_id is null 
  connect by prior id = parent_id
```

How this structure can be even more convenient?

Comment: Yes, it's just a standard parent-child self-referential structure. In Rails I'd probably use something like Google's visualisation API via the google_visualr gem -- look for something similar.

Comment: thanks Egor / David. yes querying the PLAN_TABLE directly rather than using `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);` in fact has the proper formatting. I think the easier for me would be to take it and put it in my own Java data structure rather than trying to find something that already does this.